# what is the probability of a couple who has four girls and is trying again for a boy. what is the probability that the next kid will be a girl?

Tags: probability, statistics

A couple has four kids already, all girls. the couple would like to have a son and would like to give it another try. what is the probability that the next kid will be a girl?

Comment: half because it's independent of the gender of the previous 4 kids

Comment: On the assumption of independence, the events are independent. Parenthetically, even without sex determination interference, more boys are born than girls. (But quite soon there are more girls: males are more fragile.)

Comment: Be sure to condition the probability on the husband being Henry VIII.

Comment: With data, we could verify if events are really independent. It is not obvious to me

Comment: This is actually a somewhat profound question, 18th century mathematician Pierre-Simon Laplace put it in another context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem

Answer (score 4):

If we presume that we know nothing about the actual probability of having a girl, $p$, then we can use [Hinkley's predictive likelihood for the binomial](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2958920?uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21103497941261) to predict the probability that the next birth will also be a girl, assuming births are *conditionally* independent, given $p$. This is sensible, since the probability that a couple will have a girl or boy is affected primarily by the X/Y ratio of the male gametes, and to some extent selective factors in the female. Therefore, while overall the bias is slightly toward male births, there will be overdispersion around this mean due to individual propensities that are at odds with the overall average.

Let $g$ be the number of girls born to date and $n$ be the number of children born to-date. For general prediction, we want to know the probability that there will be $r$ girls in the next $s\geq r$ births.

$P(r|g,n,s) = K\frac{{n \choose g}{s \choose r}}{n+s\choose g+r}$, where $K$ is a normalizing constant to make $\sum\limits_{r=0}^s\frac{{n \choose g}{s \choose r}}{n+s\choose g+r} = 1$

In your case, we are dealing with $s=1$ and $n=g=4$, which greatly simplifies things, since  there are only two outcomes ($r=0,r=1$) and ${1\choose 0} = {1 \choose 1} = 1$. 
The simplified formula is:

$P(r|4,4,1) = K\frac{{4 \choose 4}{1 \choose r}}{5\choose 4+r}= K\frac{(4+r)!(r)!}{120} = K\left( \frac{1}{5}+\frac{4r}{5}\right)$, (since $r$ can only be $1$ or $0$)

In this case, there are only two values of $r$ so getting $K$ is easy:
$P(r=0|4,4,1) + P(r=1|4,4,1) = 1 \rightarrow K \left( \frac{1}{5} + 1\right) = 1 \therefore K=\frac{5}{6}$

Given the above, the probability that the next child is a girl, given that all 4 previous children were girls, is: $P(r=1|4,4,1)=\frac{5}{6} \approx 83\%$

A more detailed exposition using more sophisticated models can be found [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2986059.pdf?acceptTC=true&acceptTC=true&jpdConfirm=true) - it studies possible models for the overdispersion of actual sex ratios in the human population, which lends evidence that the probability of having a girl can vary either between families or even within a single family over time.

Comment: How could meiosis possibly be changed to produce a different X/Y ratio? That alters the fundamental aspects of the process.

Comment: $\frac 5 6$ is the answer you get if you assume a uniform distribution of bias towards sex, but here you seem to assume a binomial distribution.  Is that a coincidence or just two different ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: @qwr I don't know the mechanism or why this happens, but the link I showed you observed overdispersion in the intra-family sex ratios, hence there is some sort of pair-effect happening. If there werent, then the undispersed binomial model would do just fine.

Comment: @DanielV you are referring to the Bayesian formulation. Hinkley used a pure likelihood approach, which does not use a prior, but it give you the same answer as a Bayesian estimate with a uniform prior.

Comment: Thanks, this is where the problem I am familiar with solving: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_problem

Comment: @Eupraxis1981   While your answer might be correct, I find it very unlikely that there could be an $83\%$ ratio, that X/Y distribution could be so far from normal and no extra info about the family is given in the problem. This answer will probably end up confusing an intro statistics student or someone like that.

Comment: @qwr When it comes to statistics, confusion might be better than incorrect confidence.  I like how Expraxis clearly lays out his assumptions; that isn't done often enough in statistics imho.

Comment: @qwr Of course, this article from chance magazine argues against any special genetic or environmental factors, so the jury is still out. http://www.isds.duke.edu/~dalene/chance/chanceweb/144.rodgers.pdf . Our exchange shows how ambiguous even a simple problem can be.

Comment: @gina If you are indeed using a textbook problem, then I'd suggest qwr's answer, as it uses the prior knowldge that births are likely to be near 50% boys. Mine makes no prior assumptions and so has the potential for more variability.

Answer (score 1):

i agree. having the 4 girls in the beginning means nothing: it does not affect if the next child will be a girl or a boy. So it is independent from everything and the chances is 50%

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be homework, so I assume the problem is not a complex biology problem and there's a 50/50 chance of boy or girl. We can assume the probabilities are independent to each other, so the probability is $50\%$.

Notes: The average male/female ratio in the world is about $1:1$, and it's safe to assume half of sperm contain an X chromosome and other half contain Y from meiosis. I think it's also safe to assume fertilization is independent.